# Formula for the midpoint in the hyperbolic geometry

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, hyperbolic-geometry

I have two questions.

First, is there a relatively simple formula for the midpoint of two points $a_1$ and $a_2$ in the disk with respect to the hyperbolic geometry?  That is, the point on the bisector of $a_1$ and $a_2$ which has minimal distance from $a_1$ and $a_2$.

Second, if $B$ denotes the degree $2$ finite Blaschke product with zeros $a_1$ and $a_2$, is the critical point of $B$ which is in the disk equal to the midpoint of $a_1$ and $a_2$?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

#### Critical point

Yes, it's at the midpoint. For Blaschke products $B$ with zeros at $\pm a$ this is immediate from the formula $B(z)=(z^2-a^2)/(1-\bar a^2 z^2)$.

If zeros are elsewhere, say $z_1,z_2$, then consider the composition $B\circ \phi^{-1}$ where $\phi$ is a Möbius transformation that sends the hyperbolic midpoint between $z_1,z_2$ to $0$. This composition is a Blaschke product with zeros $\phi(z_1),\phi(z_2)$ which satisfy $\phi(z_1)+\phi(z_2)=0$, reducing the problem to the previous case.

#### Midpoint

The connection with Blaschke product might be the easiest approach. Move one of points to zero, the other goes to

$$ c = \frac{a_1-a_2}{1-a_1\bar a_2}$$
The midpoint between $0$ and $c$ can be found by differentiating $z(z-c)/(1-\bar cz)$. When $c$ is between $0$ and $1$ (can be achieved by rotation), it's 
$$
d = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-c^2}}{c} 
$$
Finally, the midpoint is obtained by undoing,
$$
m = \frac{d+a_2}{1+m\bar a_2}
$$

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that degree 1 blaschke products preserve hyperbolic distances, which basically gives it to you.  For the midpoint, I have already done the calculations you are suggesting, and what I get is a horrendous mess of $a_1$'s, $a_2$'s, and square roots, which I have not managed to  simplify substantially.  I was curious whether there is some other approach which gives a "relatively simple formula" for the hyperbolic midpoint/critical point in terms of $a_1$ and $a_2$.